# Failure with Firebase Analytics when archiving IOS code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics

When I try to archive archive my IOS code, I see the following error. Does anyone know whats the code and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: yes I have this in my PodFile 
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf Pods && pod install`?

Comment: yes I have tried that

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: version 12.3 @PaulBeusterien

Comment: Perhaps `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`