# 'db/version_edit.h' file not found because of Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm getting the following error when trying to archive my IOS code

```
#include "db/version_edit.h"
```

'db/version_edit.h' file not found

I have the following in my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.2'

target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Minuteapp
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'AppAuth','~> 1.2.0'
  pod 'SwiftMessages' , '7.0.0'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Promises' 
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds' #Advertising Pod (requires Analytics)
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging'
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK’
  pod 'ApphudSDK'
  pod 'FittedSheets', '2.1.1'
  pod 'SideMenu'
  pod 'ColorThiefSwift', '>= 0.4.1'
  pod "SwiftChart"
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'AQPlayer'
  pod 'DeviceKit'
  pod "SwiftRater"
  # pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
  pod "STPopup"
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'OptimizelySwiftSDK', '~> 3.3.2'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
end
```

Comment: That file should be found in the leveldb pod, a dependency of `Firebase/Database`. Something in the Xcode project settings may be messing up the generated header search paths that CocoaPods generates in the xcworkspace.

Comment: Just a FYI, *The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.* See [Available Pods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods) section. You've also got Analytics listed twice and what is the pod *Firebase*? Also, probably a good idea to use single ticks instead of quotes for consistency.

Comment: Hi @PaulBeusterien If that is the case, how do I fix it? Can you please help?

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the Build Settings in the Xcode project.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I SEE ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/leveldb-library/leveldb.framework UNDER Input files

Comment: Thanks @PaulBeusterien. Do you have an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496206/failure-with-firebase-analytics-when-archiving-ios-code? Thanks so much!

Comment: @PaulBeusterien What version of XCode are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the leveldb headers get found in my version of the [FirebaseDatabase](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/database) quickstart:

[image]

Comment: Next step would be to check the Xcode build log and debug the failing command.

Comment: Or binary search adding/subtracting Pods between the quickstart and your project

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: The quickstart works on all Xcode 12 versions up to the current 12.5. beta